# R Error for dplyr summarize

Tags: r

Im sure that this has worked prior:

```
visit_dauer_tab <- data_2 %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(visit_id) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(first_visit = min(date_time), 
               last_visit = max(date_time), 
               dauer = (last_visit-first_visit)*60)
```

I have a dataframe with unique Visit_ids. Every Visits ID has many rows, in column date_time ist the timestamp (e.g: 2018-05-08 11:42:18)
I want to calculate for each Visit_id the duration (max(datetime) minus min(datetime)) in minutes.
Suddenly, after starting new R-session, I get an error message:

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
Evaluation error: non numerical Argument für binairy Operator.
```

How can this be?

Comment: Can you show us `str(data_2)`? Be sure to have dates as Date obj.

Comment: RLave. date_time : POSIXct, format: "2018-05-08 11:42:18" "2018-05-08 11:42:52"

Comment: Now Iam confused: I unload plyr and dplyr, and now it works again

Comment: I think its a collision of dplyr and plyr. This post/question can be closed. With unloaded plyr, it works.  This post can be closed.